# Sql Developer can conect Oracle Database 12c with TNS but can not connected with basic

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, tnsnames

I have installed a new oracle database(12.2.0.1). I have create a pluggable database (orclpdb). I create a user Fed_Test_User in the PDB. And I can connect it by SQL developer with TNS(can connect by conn Fed_Test_User/welcome@orclpdb). But I can not connect by SQL Developer with basic connection type.

Listener.ora:

```
 LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

sqlnet.ora:

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

tnsnames.ora:

```
LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.us.oracle.com)
    )
  )


ORCLPDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME =orclpdb.us.oracle.com)
    )
  )
```

lsnrctl status:

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                14-SEP-2018 20:38:13
Uptime                    0 days 2 hr. 46 min. 28 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /scratch/jxi/oracleDB/product/12c/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /scratch/jxi/oracleDB/diag/tnslsnr/slc16vyj/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=slc16vyj.us.oracle.com)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=/scratch/jxi/oracleDB/admin/orcl/xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "75e0ec7d5ff26817e053f5e0f50a1fa4.us.oracle.com" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orcl.us.oracle.com" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orclXDB.us.oracle.com" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orclpdb.us.oracle.com" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

anything I missed? Hope someone can help me. Thanks;

Answer (score 2):

When connecting to the PDB, you must use the SERVICE name.

The SID is for the container database only.

[image]

[See this page, specifically working with PDBs](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/database/multitenant-part1-pdbs-2193987.html)

```
Service Name. When you create a PDB, Oracle automatically adds it as a service in the listener. You can confirm it by looking at the listener status: 

[oracle@prosrv1 trace]$ lsnrctl status
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on 24-FEB-2013 12:20:14
Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle. All rights reserved.
Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias LISTENER
Version TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date 19-FEB-2013 21:09:05
Uptime 4 days 15 hr. 11 min. 9 sec
Trace Level off
Security ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP OFF
Listener Parameter File
/u02/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/grid/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File
/u02/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/prosrv1/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=prosrv1.proligence.com)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "+ASM" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "+ASM", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "CONA" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "CONA", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "CONAXDB" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "CONA", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "pdb1" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "CONA", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
The service "pdb1" actually points to the PDB called PDB1. It's very important to note that that this is not a service name in initialization parameter of the database, as you can see from the service_names parameter of the database.

SQL> show parameter service
NAME TYPE VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
service_names string CONA
You can place that service name in an entry in the TNSNAMES.ORA file:

PDB1 =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = prosrv1.proligence.com)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = PDB1)
)
)
Now you can connect to PDB1 using the connect string:

[oracle@prosrv1 ~]$ sqlplus system/oracle@pdb1
```

Answer (score 0):

[connect with TNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJe5w.png)

[connect with basic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZ13T.png)

By the way. I can connect the CDB by the SQL developer with basic connection type.

[connect CDB with basic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxr0E.png)

Comment: edit your question, add these screenshots to your question, don't use an answer to add information to your question